# docker-compose for a single container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I always see docker-compose intended for multi-container use

It seems to me that it is just as useful for a single container as it codifies what can be a very long command sent to docker run

I haven't seen any documentation recommending a docker-compose.yml with a single container defined.

Am I missing a reason to prefer the cli approach to putting the arguments in docker-compose.yml?

Thanks,

Kent

Comment: I also wonder, so have you got a reason now to share?

Comment: Given the existence of tools like composerize.com that turn a single docker run command line into a docker-compose file for a single container, I assume running single containers with docker-compose must be a fairly common practice. However, I have refrained from posting an answer because I am not clear on what all of the differences there might be between running directly with docker and running docker-compose for a single container. I defer to someone more experienced/knowledgeable.